# Language of date

Tags: android, date

I want to print the date in french language.
For example "Janvier" and not "January".

I am using this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.FRENCH);
Date date = null;
            try {
                date = mDateFormat.parse(document.date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But it doesn't work!

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this...

```
public class FormatDateLocale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        // Defines an array of Locale we are going to use for 
        // formatting date information.
        //
        Locale[] locales = new Locale[] {
                Locale.JAPAN,
                Locale.CHINA,
                Locale.KOREA,
                Locale.TAIWAN,
                Locale.ITALY,
                Locale.FRANCE,
                Locale.GERMAN
        };

        // Get an instance of current date time
        Date today = new Date();

        //
        // Iterates the entire Locale defined above and create a long 
        // formatted date using the SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance() 
        // with the format, the Locale and the date information.
        //
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            System.out.println("Date format in " 
                + locale.getDisplayName() 
                + " = " 
                + SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(
                      SimpleDateFormat.LONG, locale)
                          .format(today).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

The result of our code are:

```
Date format in Japanese (Japan) = 2009/01/04
Date format in Chinese (China) = 2009年1月4日
Date format in Korean (South Korea) = 2009년 1월 4일 (일)
Date format in Chinese (Taiwan) = 2009年1月4日
Date format in Italian (Italy) = 4 GENNAIO 2009
Date format in French (France) = 4 JANVIER 2009
Date format in German = 4. JANUAR 2009
```

Source Link: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/415.html