# Android: Parsing months with locale

Tags: android, locale, monthcalendar

Hi there everybody: is there any way I can parse a month -my app will be both in dutch and in english, so for example October could be either Oktober or October- and depending on it, set the corresponding month of the year? (October would be the 10th for example).

The server always replies with a String (which is the name of a month IN DUTCH) but I need to parse this, because the app will be also in ENGLISH).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9904658/1160207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DateFormat symbols which is locale aware.  Don't try to hard code month names.

```
DateFormatSymbols(Locale.DUTCH).getMonths()[Calendar.OCTOBER]; // returns Oktober
```

Or

```
Calendar.getDisplayNames(MONTH, ALL_STYLES, Locale.DUTCH); // returns a map which you can use to match strings
```

If you are getting the month name string from somewhere else, you can convert it to a month number:

```
DateTime instance = format.withLocale(Locale.DUTCH).parseDateTime("Oktober");  
int monthNum = instance.getMonthOfYear();
```

Comment: I used the first one with a slight modification, but very good, thanks!

Comment: A suggestion for your answer `DateFormatSymbols(Locale.DUTCH).getMonths()[10];`. Instead of using the int `10` you could (and maybe should) also use the constant `Calendar.OCTOBER`.